# Is it safe to return std::wstring from a DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, c++11, std, wchar

According to some older StackOverflow questions ( [Unable to pass std::wstring across DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177907/unable-to-pass-stdwstring-across-dll/15178021#15178021) , [C++ DLL returning pointer to std::list<std::wstring>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750293/c-dll-returning-pointer-to-stdliststdwstring/13751441#13751441) ) it's not considered safe for a C++ DLL to return a `std::wstring` because there's no guarantee the main program has the same definition of `std::wstring` and therefore it might cause a crash.

However, in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string , it seems `std::wstring` can be used interchangeably with a `WCHAR` array now:

> (Since C++11)
>   The elements of a basic_string are stored contiguously, that is, for a basic_string s, &*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n for any n in [0, s.size()), or, equivalently, a pointer to s[0] can be passed to functions that expect a pointer to the first element of a CharT[] array.

I've tested this by passing `&s[0]` to a WINAPI function that expected a `WCHAR*` buffer and it appeared to work (the `std::wstring` was correctly populated with the results of the WINAPI). So since `std::wstring` can apparently be treated like a `WCHAR` array now, I decided to revisit this question: can a `std::wstring` be safely returned from a DLL? Why or why not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing has changed with regards passing C++ objects across DLL boundaries. That is still not allowed for the same reason as before. The module on the other side of the boundary may have a different definition of the class.

The fact that `&s[0]` is a valid modifiable pointer to character array is not really relevant. Because a `std::basic_string` is a lot more than just an array of characters.

Remember that each implementation of `std::basic_string` can have different internal storage. Can have a different implementation for `operator[]`. Can be allocated off a different heap. And so on.

I think it is safe to assume that it will never be valid to pass C++ objects across general DLL boundaries. It is only viable if you guarantee that both sides of the boundary are linked against the same runtime instance.

Comment: I'm confused as to why a `std::wstring` can be safely passed to a WinAPI but not to a program built with a different C++ compiler. Wouldn't the direct modification of the `wstring`'s character array invalidate whatever other information the `wstring` implementation has? But for some reason that worked, so it seemed intuitive to me that `wstring` had gotten more receptive to other forms of modification/assignment.

Comment: You don't pass a `std::wstring` to a Win32 API function. You let a `std::wstring` supply you with a `wchar_t*`, into which it is allowed to write. The Win32 API function is indeed modifying the internal character buffer. But a `std::wstring` is much more than a character buffer.

Comment: I understand that I'm passing the `wstring`'s character buffer, not the `wstring` itself, to the WinAPI. But wouldn't the `wstring` be invalidated when its character buffer is directly modified like that? Hence my assumption that the class had gotten more robust and/or compatible with other classes.

Comment: What do you mean by "invalidated"? Remember that `std::basic_string` has always supplied modifiable references to its character buffer. That's what `operator[]` does. What you are missing in the comments is that `std::basic_string` contains more that a character buffer.

Comment: I always understood the previous problems in passing `wstring` to a WinAPI function to be because `wstring` kept track of its internal buffer in some way, and modifying that buffer directly would corrupt the rest of the `wstring`'s information. Was that not the case?

Comment: No, that was not the case.

Comment: @computerfreaker Think of it like this. Suppose that one runtime defines `std::basic_string` as a class with private members `buffer` and `length`. But the other runtime does exactly the same with the members in the opposite order. Neither runtime can understand the other's types. They are simply different types. That is fundamentally what it boils down to. And there are other issues too. Like calling convention potentially being different. Allocation off different heaps. Really, the list of problems is endless!

Comment: So the `length` would still be valid after the `wstring`'s buffer was passed to a WinAPI, but this `wstring` definition would conflict with one where the `buffer` and `length` are switched... this explains my question perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Probably worth noting that if its an "internal" dll used only by your app, and you build everything with the same compiler, compiler settings, libs etc then it will actually work without any issues.