# How to return a string from a C++ DLL into a MetaTrader 4 code-execution ecosystem?

Tags: c++, string, dll, mql4, metatrader4

I have following function

```
__declspec(dllexport) wchar_t* __stdcall __getJson(wchar_t * listN){
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
//function logic
wstring ant = utf8_to_wstring(result);
const WCHAR* constRes = ant.c_str();
WCHAR* tempObj=new WCHAR[ant.length()];
wcscpy(tempObj, constRes);
thread Thread([tempObj]{
    Sleep(1000);
    delete[] tempObj;
});
Thread.detach();
return tempObj;
}
```

This DLL returns **`wchar_t*`** to MetaTrader4.

I tried many ways to return correct value and avoid memory leaks such as set return type `const wchar_t*`, creating my own class with destructor with `delete[]` in. But all this attempts was unsuccessful: I got `'??ello'` instead of `'hello'`. Just first one or two symbols were incorrect. With creating `thread` it works right. But, I want to know, may there be better solution?

Comment: Are you following the golden rule? _If your DLL allocates it, your DLL must free it_.

Comment: Also i should point out that the memory you are allocating is one element too short.

Comment: @paddy, yes I try.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646989/is-it-safe-to-return-stdwstring-from-a-dll

Comment: @sailfish009, I tried to return `&ant[0]`. It was same `'??ello'`

Comment: try std::wstring instead of wchar_t *

Comment: Could you kindly disambiguate: **Is this DLL used in a use-case** on a MetaTrader **Terminal** 4 **or Server side?**

Comment: @user3666197, in use-case

Comment: **Question was:** Is the DLL called from an MT4-**Server** side *( i.e. from a Broker-operated Dealing Infrastructure )*? Or is the DLL called from an MT4-**Terminal** side *( i.e. from a trader's Terminal )*? **+** StackOverflow Policy of MCVE-compliant posts ought **include** the actual calling-side code, which asks the DLL-service.

Comment: @user3666197, this Dll called from MT4-Terminal side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentaly, I put my mind to `BOOL APIENTRY DllMain`. So it solve my problem without creating threads.

```
vector<wchar_t*> tempObjVector;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,LPVOID lpReserved)
{
   switch (ul_reason_for_call)
   {
   case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
   case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
   case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
   case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH: 
       while (tempObjVector.size() != 0)
       {
           delete[] tempObjVector.back();
           tempObjVector.pop_back();
       }
       break;
   }
   return TRUE;
}

__declspec(dllexport) wchar_t* __stdcall __getJson(wchar_t * listN){
    ....
    ....
    wchar_t* tempObj=new wchar_t[ant.length()+1];
    tempObj[ant.length()] = 0;
    wcscpy(tempObj, constRes);
    tempObjVector.push_back(tempObj);
    return tempObj;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To create a string in your DLL and pass it to the caller, you must dynamically allocate some memory in the DLL to store the string's characters, and pass a pointer to that memory to the caller.

Moreover, the caller must be able to release that memory when the string is not needed anymore.

To make it work properly, you must use the *same* memory manager/allocator to both allocate and free the string's memory.

One option would be to use a common system-wide allocator like the COM allocator. In this way, you can allocate the memory in the DLL using `CoTaskMemAlloc`, and the caller can free it using the matching `CoTaskMemFree`.

Another option would be to return a `BSTR` string, allocated with `SysAllocString` in the DLL. And the caller would release that string invoking `SysFreeString`.

Or, you could provide a custom function to free the string's memory in your DLL. For example, you could allocate the string's memory in your DLL using `new[]`, and you could provide a `MyDllFreeString` function that invokes `delete[]`.

Note that, when you allocate memory for a C-style string, you must consider an additional slot for the string's *NUL-terminator* (so, you must allocate `stringLength + 1` `wchar_t`s).

Comment: You might want to know, the **receiver-side** of the DLL-block-of-data is a specific code-execution environment, in which some C-common features do not hold. While the **`MQL4`**-syntax was since it's initial days inspired by C-family of languages (+still creeping, under internal developments of the engine ), the `MQL4`-language compiler does have a lot of non-C specialties, so the problem is in expecting a `MQL4`-side **`struct`**, instead of a C-side **`string`**. You might want to update your post to reflect these facts so as to properly meet the asked `MQL4`-context of use. Long live C64!

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing that (a little bit simpler, but for some cases only):

```
//C++
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) const wchar_t *GetMessage();
const wchar_t *GetMessage()
{
    static std::wstring last_message;
    last_message = GetSomeMessage();
    return last_message.c_str();
}

//MQL
#import "MyDll.dll"
string GetMessage();
#import
string message = GetMessage();
```

Comment: you are life saver wow. Been slamming my head into integrating a C++ dll function into MQL5 that returns a string. I wanted to use a std::string but was having issues so tried using char* but was getting super confused. THANKS YOU ARE AWESOME :D

Comment: pure genius answer

Answer (score 1):

### #<sup>ol' ASM hackers always used to start with</sup>
`#assume nothing             ; mql4_string != string`

Bingo, the headbang is evident. Receiving side does not assume, since *New*-`MQL4.56789` was introduced, it's representation of a block of bytes as a **`string`**, but a **`struct` (!)**.

> *(cit.:)* Internal representation of the string type is a structure of 12 bytes long:

```
#pragma pack(push,1) 
struct MqlString 
       { 
                int      size;       // 32-bit integer, contains size of the buffer, allocated for the string. 
                LPWSTR   buffer;     // 32-bit address of the buffer, containing the string. 
                int      reserved;   // 32-bit integer, reserved. 
                }; 
#pragma pack(pop,1)
```

> *(cit.:)*  **<sup>( MQL4-side doc: )</sup>
> `String Type`**
>   The **`string`** type is used for storing text strings. A text string is a sequence of characters in the Unicode format with the final zero at the end of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, using MqlString struct leads to access violation error in MetaTrader4. I read about this structure and already tried to use it as output of function but accidentaly found at one of forums, that using wchar_t* is better choice.

Comment: @VladislavVazhenin Yes, many issues ( just imagine re-design efforts for all the code-base .. ). Most of the times we created a new DLL-wrapper, which returns to MQL4-side a "*New*-`MQL4.56789` compatible" `char[]` and translate this using an MQL4 built-in functions ( to avoid any memory management ), whereas the DLL-proxy reformats the calling interface so as to meet the external DLL-function specifications. This approach was the least bleeding, once the whole re-design expenses and efforts had to be re-taken again. One never knows, when a next syntax-creep appears on the table, do we?

Comment: for me is strangely, that information about definition mql string in manual is same as you suggested. So users must experiment with casting types....

Comment: Welcome to **The Club**! While **`#assume nothing`** methodology helps a bit to survive the speed of change(s) [ ... & still creeping ], it is burning a lot of fat, attention & both design and testing efforts. Quite a paranoid world, isn't it? But it helps in building a systematically robust, self-healing solution approaches.  Relying on naive and optimistic belief that all initial assumptions will hold forever, is systematically punished on each arrival of such change. This is The Green Tree of Human Life  :o)

Comment: n.b.: the above cited `#pragma`-wrapped `struct` internal definition was not "*suggested*", but was a citation from ***New-*`MQL4.56789`**, to make pure C++ guys start to believe in what I saying -- it was rather a warning, that without this internal know-how, one cannot solve the DLL-interface from just C-side. What I did suggest, was to systematically avoid any such dependence and to work with **`char[]`** and built-in `MQL4` conversion-functions, that ought ( remain to ) understand all `MQL4` code-execution internal "surprises" not seen from outside. Anyway- **Enjoy Wild Worlds of `MQL4`**.